# How to create user that has permission to create new sites on WordPress with multisite option enabled?

Tags: plugins, multisite, user-roles

I have installed user roles editor plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/ and created new role, but can't make this role to give the user ability to create new sites on WordPress with multisite option enabled.